# I am not able to install rise of nation in windows 7

Tags: rise-of-nations

I have RiseOfNationXTrial.exe setup file. I choose run as administrator from right click menu. Entered the password in admin password prompt. The cursor changed to wait cursor for some time and just changed normal. The setup did not start.

Environment Details

```
Windows 7 Enterprise
DirectX Updated before game install
NVIDEA GForce graphics card.
```

What is wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: Where'd you get the file? Maybe the download was corrupted. Have you set the file to use XP compatibility mode?

Comment: did the download from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8796

Answer (score 1):

From the download link you provided, If you click on 'System Requirements' tab below the download button you can see that Windows 7 is not listed as compatible OS.

> Supported Operating System:
>   Windows 2000, Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows ME, Windows XP

You have to run the setup file in compatibility mode with one of the OS above.

1) Right-click on the file and select 'Properties'

2) Click on the 'Compatibility' tab

3) In the section 'Compatibility mode', click on the 'Run this program in compatibility mode for' check box.

4) From the list below select 'Windows XP (Service Pack 3)' and click OK.

This procedure worked for me and I was able to install it. However when I tried to run the game, nothing happened. So I had to do the same procedure for the patriots.exe file. It is located in the main directory of the game.

Give it a try and you shouldn't have any problems running the game.

Comment: Great advise. You inspired me to grab my gold edition discs and play it again.